# Determine if Array Has Elements in IF/Then Statement In Bash

Tags: bash, if-statement

I'm trying to determine if an array has elements in an if/then statement like this:

```
if [[ -n "$aws_user_group" && -n "${#aws_user_roles[@]}" ]]; then
  echo "$aws_user_name,$aws_user_group,"${aws_user_roles[*]}",$aws_key,$aws_account_number" >> "$ofile"
 elif [[ -n "$aws_user_group" ]]; then
  echo "$aws_user_name,$aws_user_group,,$aws_key,$aws_account_number" >> "$ofile"
fi
```

Problem is, if the array is empty it's represented by '0' as in this debug output:

```
   [[ -n 0 ]]
```

And the wrong line prints out. It prints the line that includes the 'role' output but leaves it blank.

How can I check a string variable and a mathematical variable in the same if/then statement?

Comment: `-n` and `-z` are non-zero and zero length *strings*, not for mathematical comparisons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zero is the number of elements. Use a mathematical evaluation.

```
if (( ${#aws_user_roles[@]} )) # HAS ELEMENTS
then echo has elements
else echo is empty
fi
```

> example

```
$: declare -i foo=()
$: if (( ${#foo[@]})); then echo elements; else echo empty; fi
empty
$: foo=( 1 2 3 )
$: if (( ${#foo[@]})); then echo elements; else echo empty; fi
elements
```

> as an aside...

```
$: foo=( 1 2 3 )
$: if (( ${#foo})); then echo elements; else echo empty; fi
elements
```

also works, but `${#foo}` is really only looking at the string length of first element, and could theoretically give you a false response...though `''` returns 1. Hmm...

You can also chain tests for other things -

```
if (( ${#var} )) && [[ -e "$var" ]] # both must succeed
```

This is the same as one-liner tests

```
ls a && ls b || echo one of these doesn't exist...
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. Any way to combine the mathematical test with the test to see if the other variable with text has a value: `-n "$aws_user_group"` ?

Comment: just use `&&` between your tests. See above.

Comment: Ok thanks. Also I tried this and it works: `if [[ -n "$aws_user_group" && -n "${aws_user_roles[@]}" ]]; then  `